# Moving a sprite from point A to point B in a specific time

Tags: java, android, oop

In my app there is a feature where you can set which way a sprite will be going in following animation, this feature looks more or less like this:

[image]

In the final animation the sprite always moves first to point 1, than from 1 to 2, 2 to 3, etc. ...and you can also set the time in which the sprite will move from one point to another.

The final animation is run by a timer, so that each 15 miliseconds the sprite moves by partialMoveX in X direction and by partialMoveY in Y direction.

`int wholeMoveX = followingPointX-currentPointX;
int partialMoveX = wholeMoveX/(specifiedTime/15);
int wholeMoveY = followingPointY-currentPointY;
int partialMoveY = wholeMoveY/(specifiedTime/15);`

But the problem is that, probably because of week RAM, the timer lags and 15 miliseconds suddenly change into let's say 80 ms, so that the movement of the sprite is noticeably slower than it should be.

Please help me. How can the sprite move frome point to point in exactly the time I want it to?

I already came with an idea that it could, instead of always moving by particalMoves, each 15 ms count how much space there is between where the sprite is and the following point and than relating it to the time it already used, something like this:

`int wholeMoveX = followingPointX-spriteX;
int remainingTime = specifiedTime+theTimeItSetOff-currentTime;
int thisTimesMoveX = wholeMoveX/(remainingTime/15);
spriteX = spriteX + thisTimesMoveX;`

, and that works, but the problem is that in this case the sprite starts slow and accelerates as it approaches the followingPoint. Also the Sprite never moves fully into the point, it always leaves a slight gap between the following point and itself.

Do you have any idea how to fix this properly?

Comment: use Animators framework: `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator`